Evaluating series using Fourier expansion
Have a look at the following question:

Find the half range cosine series of $f(x)=x-x^2$ in the interval $(0, \pi)$. Hence, find the sum of the series $1+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\ldots$

My attempt:
Taking $f(x)=x-x^2, 0 \leqslant x \leqslant \pi $, we get
$$f(x) \approx \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L},$$
where
\begin{align*}
a_0
&=\frac{2}{L} \int_0^L f(x) d x \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_c^\pi x-x^2 d x \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_0^\pi \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\frac{\pi^3}{3}\right] \\
&=\pi-\frac{2 \pi^2}{3},
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
a_n
&=\frac{2}{L} \int_0^L f(x) \cos \frac{n \pi x}{L} d x \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi\left(x-x^2\right) \cos n x d x \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\left[\frac{-1}{n^2}+\frac{-n(2 \pi-1)(-1)^n}{n^3}\right] \\
&=\frac{-2}{\pi n^2}((2 \pi-1)(-1)^n+1) \\
&=\frac{4 \pi-2}{n^2 \pi}(-1)^{n+1}-\frac{2}{n^2\pi}.
\end{align*}
I am not getting any series having $n-$th term containing $1/n^4$ out of here. I tried with $x=0,\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}$, etc. But none of them was working. Any combinations possible?

Might involve Parseval's Theorem
